# Remove duplicate strings from output - shell

Tags: linux, shell, dpkg

I have a command that does a dpkg query to see what versions of Tomcat are installed on my system. I am trying to get unique values and remove duplicates. However, I am still seeing duplicates in my output.

Command:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep -Eo 'tomcat[0-9]?' | uniq
```

Output:

```
tomcat8
tomcat9
tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Desired Output:

```
tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Comment: `uniq` only works on sorted lists. As people have pointed out below `sort -u` works well for this, but if you were dead-set on using `uniq` just add a `sort`after the `grep` and before the `uniq`.

Answer (score 2):

From `man uniq`:

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.
> You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.
> Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'.

Using `sort -u` will sort and print only unique lines:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep -Eo 'tomcat[0-9]?' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

[sort -u](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) should work.

I tested using a simple text file but it functions the same with piped input.

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt 
tomcat8
tomcat9
tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Using `sort -u`:

```
$ sort -u /tmp/test.txt 
tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Using `uniq` produces the same results you were experiencing:

```
$ uniq /tmp/test.txt 
tomcat8
tomcat9
tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a single `awk` you can do this:

```sh
dpkg-query -l |
awk 'match($0, /tomcat[0-9]*/) && !seen[s=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)]++ {print s}'

tomcat8
tomcat9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aptitude search ~itomcat[0-9] | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following: Some extra info is added to assist anyone in need.

```
sort -u your_file_with_records.txt #this will remove the duplicates
 
tomcat8
tomcat9

uniq –c your_file_with_records.txt #this will print the count 

2 tomcat8
2 tomcat9

uniq –u your_file_with_records.txt #prints only unique lines of a file, in your case it will be empty because of having no unique lines
```